# How do I remove the extra space in in this search box (between input field and button)

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot of form]

In this image you can see a visible extra space in between input field and search button. I want to remove this space and make them close. If I'm wrong somewhere in my coding, please tell me the solution. How can I overcome this problem?

And, here's my code:

```css
input[type=text].search_input {
    width: 350px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('assets/imgs/asd.png');
    background-position: 7px 4.5px;
    border-top-right-radius:  0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:  0px;
    border-top-left-radius:  5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
    border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
    border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.search {
    border-top-right-radius:  5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:  5px;
    border-top-left-radius:  0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
    border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
    border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
    padding: 0px 19px 0px 19px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background:#0073f5;
    outline: none;
    color : white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
  <input class="search_input" id="search" type="text" name="q">
  <button class="search" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Insert `float:left` like this:*

```
input[type=text].search_input {
    float: left;
    //other codes....
}
```

```css
input[type=text].search_input {
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('assets/imgs/asd.png');
  background-position: 7px 4.5px;
  border-top-right-radius:  0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:  0px;
  border-top-left-radius:  5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
  border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  float: left;
}
.search {
  border-top-right-radius:  5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:  5px;
  border-top-left-radius:  0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
  border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
  padding: 0px 19px 0px 19px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background:#0073f5;
  outline: none;
  color : white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
  <input class="search_input" id="search" type="text" name="q">
  <button class="search" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just add `display: flex` to the `form` element:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=text].search_input {
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('assets/imgs/asd.png');
  background-position: 7px 4.5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-left: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.search {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-left: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
  border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
  padding: 0px 19px 0px 19px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #0073f5;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
  <input class="search_input" id="search" type="text" name="q">
  <button class="search" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using the `float` layout property is to give the button a negative left margin:

```
.search {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```css
input[type=text].search_input {
width: 350px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('assets/imgs/asd.png');
background-position: 7px 4.5px;
border-top-right-radius:  0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:  0px;
border-top-left-radius:  5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
outline: none;
font-size: 16px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.search {
border-top-right-radius:  5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:  5px;
border-top-left-radius:  0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-top:2px solid #0073f5;
border-left:2px solid #0073f5;
border-bottom: 2px solid #0073f5;
border-right: 0px solid #0073f5;
margin-left: -4px;
padding: 0px 19px 0px 19px;
width: 110px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 16px;
background:#0073f5;
outline: none;
color : white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input class="search_input" id="search" type="text" name="q">
<button class="search" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 solutions.

As your input and button are in line, you can use `margin-left: -5px` to the button

or you can use a float to the input.

```
float: left;
```